# Android ringtone preference - fetch data

Tags: android, ringtone, preference

i have a ringtone preference. How can i get the selection? I have the following kind-of-code:

```
if(preferences.getString("ringtonePref", "n/a") != ??)
            {
                Toast.makeText(TutorialPref.this,   "Chosen ringtone: silent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if(preferences.getString("ringtonePref", "n/a") != "DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI" )
            {
                Toast.makeText(TutorialPref.this,   "Chosen ringtone: + default", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you assign the selection to your notification instance.

```
String strRingtonePreference = preferences.getString("ringtonePref", "DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI");
notification.sound = Uri.parse(strRingtonePreference);
```

Where notification is :

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, time);
```

You will find more info here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html

Comment: `"DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI"` doesn't work. Rather pass `null` as that argument, and call `RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri` instead of `Uri.parse` if `SharedPreferences.getString` returns `null`.

Comment: `Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI` is a good default as well when the preference returns null.